# Почему некорректно показывается кириллица в браузере?

Tags: php, io

Я использую функцию `file_get_contents` для вывода содержания файла в браузер.

```
echo file_get_contents('text.txt');
```

[image: Вывод.]

В этом файле содержатся русские символы, которые после чего неправильно отображаются на браузере. С чем это связано?

Также, я попробовал вывести этот текст из файла HTML, где содержится мета-тег `<meta charset="utf-8">`, но вывод такой же.

Comment: а текстовый файл у вас в какой кодировке хранится? подозреваю что совсем не в utf8

Comment: Как и сказали выше, либо перекодируйте файл, если он не динамичный, либо воспользуйтесь перекодировкой на лету: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/

Comment: А как поменять кодировку файла?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.